# software / plugin recommendation for creating sci-fi sound effects

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, film-sound-design, scifi

I am relatively adept with serum synth creation and music production with Ableton, but i am also developing a 3D cartoon so i need to make unique sound effects for things like ray guns, ship engines, energy beams, portals, and alien creatures. I was wondering what other softwares or plugin recommendations I could get for creating these types of unique sound effects. Thanks!